# How to access internal timers in CANoe?

Tags: ip, ethernet, can-bus, capl, canoe

I am using Ethernet bus in CANoe and want to access the internal timers used in CANoe. For example: If a packet is sent/received, the time at which the packet sent/received is to be monitored. Are there IP layer functions/System variables which can monitor this activity. Ultimately the aim is to take decision (connection shutdown) according to the time monitored.

Answer (score 1):

For received Ethernet packet there is a CAPL-function EthGetThisTimeNS, which returns time stamp in nanoseconds. Find more explanation and an example how to use it in the Help:

CAPL Functions » Ethernet » Ethernet Interaction Layer » EthGetThisTimeNS

Using C# it's more comfortable, all frame types of all bus systems implement IFrame interface with a property TimeNS == time stamp of the frame in nanoseconds as int64